When changing a cube scale size in runtime at Realtime the cube size change not smooth and in very large units. how to make it change smooth?
first i tried this:
public int cubeSize = 40;
public float fontSize = 5f;
public bool syncSizes = false;

private List<TextMeshProUGUI> textComponents = new List<TextMeshProUGUI>();

private const float MinFontSize = 10f; // Minimum font size
private float MaxFontSize = 100f; // Maximum font size based on cube size, adjust if necessary

private int oldCubeSize;

private GameObject cube;

private void Awake()
{
    oldCubeSize = cubeSize;
    MaxFontSize = cubeSize;
    cube = createCube("Cube", cubeSize);
}

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (oldCubeSize != cubeSize)
    {
        cube.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (cubeSize, cubeSize, cubeSize);

        oldCubeSize = cubeSize;
    }
}

then tried this
public int cubeSize = 40;
public float fontSize = 5f;
public bool syncSizes = false;

private List<TextMeshProUGUI> textComponents = new List<TextMeshProUGUI>();

private const float MinFontSize = 10f; // Minimum font size
private float MaxFontSize = 100f; // Maximum font size based on cube size, adjust if necessary

private int oldCubeSize;

private GameObject cube;

private void Awake()
{
    oldCubeSize = cubeSize;
    MaxFontSize = cubeSize;
    cube = createCube("Cube", cubeSize);
}

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    // Calculate the desired scale factor based on the new size.
    // This assumes the cube's original size is 1x1x1 units.
    float scaleFactor = cubeSize / 1f; // Replace 1f with the cube's actual edge length in units if different.

    if (oldCubeSize != cubeSize)
    {
        // Apply the calculated scale factor.
        cube.transform.localScale = new Vector3(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, scaleFactor);

        oldCubeSize = cubeSize;
    }
}

but in both case when changing the cubeSize value in the inspector in runtime at Realtime the cube is getting very very large even if i change the value by one from 40 to 41.
this is the cube when running first time with the size 40

now i'm changing the value from 40 to 41 but the cube is getting very large

how can i make it scale the cube in small units smooth ? got lost.

i think this is a logic solution.  cube.transform.localScale = new Vector3 (cube.transform.localScale.x - 0.01f, cube.transform.localScale.y - 0.01f, cube.transform.localScale.z - 0.01f); it's not the solution but the logic.  to decrease/increase the cube size by small units.   am i in the right direction ?

You need any further help on this issue?

The following script scales an assigned cube cobeToScale from the inspector or a self-generated cube (if none assigned) over the period of scaleDuration seconds to a cube size with edges of length targetCubeSize. You can specify a spawn position cubeSpawnPos if you don't assign a cube. Also, font size cubeTextFontSize´of the numbers on the cube's faces can be set:
using System.Collections;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class IncreaseCubeSize : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Tooltip("Assign cube object if you want it to be scaled. If not specified, script creates own cube")]
    public GameObject cubeToScale;
    [Tooltip("The target cube size. Denotes the length of one cube edge (in meters)")]
    public float targetCubeSize = 3;
    [Tooltip("Duration over which cube is to be scaled (in seconds)")]
    public float scaleDuration = 3f;
    [Tooltip("Global position to spawn cube if script creates its own")]
    public Vector3 cubeSpawnPos = Vector3.zero;
    [Tooltip("Font size of cube face number. By default 10")]
    public float cubeTextFontSize = 10;

    void Start()
    {
        // Scale cube on start to target cube size. Pass current cube scale as parameter
        StartCoroutine(ScaleCube());
    }

    // Creates a cube with number 1 - 6 on each side using TMP Text
    private GameObject CreateCube()
    {
        // Create basic cube GameObject. Spawn at provided position. Set size to target edge length
        GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
        cube.transform.localPosition = cubeSpawnPos;
        cube.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f); // By default 1x1x1 cube

       // Array of directions in which to place text numbers (1 - 6). Order important!
        Vector3[] cubeFaceDirections = { Vector3.forward, Vector3.down, Vector3.right, Vector3.left, Vector3.up, Vector3.back };
        // Array of necessary rotations for text
        Quaternion[] cubeFaceRotations = { Quaternion.Euler(0f, 180f, 0f), Quaternion.Euler(-90f, 0f, 0f), Quaternion.Euler(0f, -90f, 0f), Quaternion.Euler(0f, 90f, 0f), Quaternion.Euler(90f, 0f, 0f), Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0, 0f) };

        // Create TextMeshPro Text children for each side with numbers 1 to 6
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            // Create text object for cube faces
            GameObject textObject = new GameObject("Text " + (i + 1));

            // Set cube as parent (text scales with cube then)
            textObject.transform.SetParent(cube.transform);
            textObject.transform.localPosition = cubeFaceDirections[i] * (cube.transform.localScale.x / 2f + 0.001f);
            textObject.transform.localRotation = cubeFaceRotations[i];

            // Add text component and set rect size to (1, 1)
            TextMeshPro cubeText = textObject.AddComponent<TextMeshPro>(); 
            textObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>().sizeDelta = Vector2.one;

            // Configure cube face text
            cubeText.text = (i + 1).ToString();
            cubeText.alignment = TextAlignmentOptions.Center;
            cubeText.fontSize = cubeTextFontSize;
            cubeText.color = Color.black;

        }

        return cube;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private IEnumerator ScaleCube()
    {
        // Check if scaling referenced cube or new cube needs to be created
        GameObject cube = (cubeToScale == null) ? CreateCube() : cubeToScale;

        // Get current cube scale
        Vector3 currentScale = cube.transform.localScale;

        // Calculate scale factor
        float scaleFactor = targetCubeSize / currentScale.x;

        // Time elapsed since the start of scaling
        float timeElapsed = 0f;

        while (timeElapsed < scaleDuration)
        {
            // Calculate the lerp parameter
            float t = timeElapsed / scaleDuration;

            // Lerp scale
            cube.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(currentScale, currentScale * scaleFactor, t);

            // Increase elapsed time
            timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;

            // Wait for next frame
            yield return null;
        }

        // Set scale definitely as Lerp does not reach final value completely
        cube.transform.localScale = currentScale * scaleFactor;
    }
}

Let me know if this is what you are looking for or if you got any questions.
Maybe as some extra resources: If you are not familiar with Coroutines, take a look at this. Alternatively, you can implement this in your Update method very similarly. If you are not familiar with Vector3.Lerp(), take a look at this. This is what achieves your desired "smooth" scaling.
